# chi squared minimization of gaussian with error bars in python and lmfit

Tags: python, plot

I am working on fitting some data to a gaussian curve using lmfit module for Python.  The fit was easy enough following some online tutorial, but I would also like to plot the error bars for this curve.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?  If your interested the data represents counts of radioactive decay per 4 seconds from Cesium-137 (x-axis represents number of counts, y-axis represents the frequency that those counts occurred).  Here is some of my code,

```
data = loadtxt('CS137gaussian.txt')
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]

def gaussian(x, amp, mu, sigma):
"1-d gaussian: gaussian(x, amp, mu, sigma)"
return (amp/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma)) * exp(-(x-mu)**2 /(2*sigma**2))

gmod = Model(gaussian)
result = gmod.fit(y, x=x, amp=20, mu=300, sigma=1)

plt.plot(x, y,         'bo')
plt.plot(x, result.init_fit, 'k--')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'r-')
```

Comment: I don't know the solution of your question since I've never used Imfit. However I need to point out that proper fit for radioactive decay is Poisson dist. not Gaussian. Gaussian dist. will just approximate the Poisson dist. when lambda in Poisson dist. is large enough (~10).

Comment: Thanks, but in this case lambda is large so it is an approximation to the gaussian.  I have a data set with small lambda as well that I will be plotting after this which will be poisson.  For now I am treating the error bars as the sqrt(frequency of counts at a particular count).

Comment: Yeah, the issue here imho is that with small lambdas your error bars don't necessarily have to be symmetric anymore, and current approach is good "enough" (but not). I know [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/errorbar_demo_features.html) can have error bars sym. and asym. alike. But you are going to have to calculate the values of them yourself. I haven't been careful enough first time to notice you're actually using mpl to plot the graph.